# Error upgrading fromSQL Server 2008 to R2

Tags: sql-server

Im trying to upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2 from SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008, but when the wizard is installing the Setup Support Files I alway get the next error:

"An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.4053",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80070057."

- I checked the CD checksum, its OK (Downloaded from MSDN)
- I cant install the VC++ Redistributable 2005 nor 2008, I get the same error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the server spec? 64 bit or 32 bit? Is there any chance you are trying to install 64bit version of SQL server on 32 bit machine?

Comment: Windows and SQL is 32 bits